# Передача функций между функциональными компонентами

Tags: reactjs

Переделываю классовые компоненты в функциональные и при передаче функции в другой компонент она становится неюзабельной, хотя webstorm подсвечивает ее, как видимую. Что я делаю не так?

```js
function MassViewer (props) {


    function AddBrand (name) {
    
    ....

        return (
            
                <div>
                    <AddOperator AddBrand={AddBrand} />
                </div>
        );
}

export function AddOperator (props) {

   ....

    function handleAddOp (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        const inputResult = inputOp;

        if (inputResult.length >= 1) {
            setMessage2('Добавлено');
            AddBrand(inputResult);
            setInputOp('');
        } else {
            setMessage('Вы не заполнили поле');
            setInputOp('')
        }
    }

        return (
            ....
        )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Затупил, надо было вызывать:

```
props.AddBrand(inputResult);
```